# Altering __RequestVerificationToken

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, antiforgerytoken

I have developed an asp.net mvc site and trying to use antiforgerytoken in Ajax post.

I can include antiforgerytoken  in the ajax request and setup that in my controller.

However, when webapp is running and I inspect browser, I can modify the __RequestVerificationToken variable before I pass it to the server.

[image]

In this example, initially it was:

```
__RequestVerificationToken: "_C9FNX_hWGQ7kndoTNZS7f-s4j44GHKQpWMnAf-862GVKleXSC…_zXqMdgXNME9uIYQy4cI0k-B5EW73oXbfys9Dmkt1vWJA2oA1"
```

But I manipulated it and changed its value to:

```
__RequestVerificationToken: "yyy"
```

My controller function receives __RequestVerificationToken without any problem, even that it was manipulated.

```
[System.Web.Mvc.HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public IHttpActionResult GrabaResolucionCiudadano([FromBody] BE_Resolucion c)
{

    BL_Resolucion b = new BL_Resolucion();
    try
    {
        c = FillDatosPrevio(c);

        if (ModeloValido)
        {
            b.SaveData(c);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    finally
    {
        b.Dispose(); b = null;
    }
}
```

How should antiforgerytoken be used?

Comment: It is supposed to validate the response; you confirmed on the server it is "yyy"?  Also, is there a user logged in at this point?

Comment: >>you confirmed on the server it is "yyy"? >>That's what is missing in my controller code, I think. Could you point out some examples about this? I have searched but didn't find.

Comment: Anti forgery token adds a form field that represents the token, which gets validated on the backend.  Check the form response data of what is posted back to see if you can see what the value is.